# wordpress remove post status count from cms

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove the post status count from WordPress `edit.php`.

[image]

My WordPress CMS have more than 500,000 posts. The publish count is loaded every time you open the page. The following query is fired every time.
This makes my Wordpress CMS loading very slow.

```
SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' GROUP BY post_status
```

Comment: Similar question is already answered on other network site [Hide the post count behind Post Views](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/hide-the-post-count-behind-post-views-remove-all-published-and-trashed-in-cus). Hope this will help you,

Comment: @cale_b "lac" is another number unit. 1 lac = 100000 (hundred thousand)

Comment: @zipkundan It will just hide the count. The query is executed in the background. I want to disable the query or modify it.

Comment: @cale_b This query took more than 15 seconds to execute.

Comment: If you remove the query you wouldn't get the list of posts!!!

Comment: @zipkundan Is there anyway to modify the query using add_action( 'load-edit.php' , 'FUNCTION_NAME' ); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By tracing the code, I've worked up the only solution that I can see.

The filter `bulk_post_updated_messages` is ONLY called on the `edit.php` screen.

The counts are not calculated (in `class-wp-posts-list-table.php`, `get_views` method) **if** the global variable `$locked_post_status` is not empty.

By gluing these two pieces of information together, I've got a solution that you can use by dropping it into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// Hook this filter, only called on the `edit.php` screen.
// It's not the "correct" filter, but it's the only one we can leverage
// so we're hijacking it a bit.
add_filter('bulk_post_updated_messages', 'suppress_counts', 10, 2);

// We need to let the function "pass through" the intended filter content, so accept the variable $bulk_messages
function suppress_counts($bulk_messages) {
    // If the GET "post_type" is not set, then it's the "posts" type
    $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? $_GET['post_type'] : 'post';

    // List any post types you would like to KEEP counts for in this array
    $exclude_post_types = array('page');
    // Global in the variable so we can modify it
    global $locked_post_status;

    // If the post type is not in the "Exclude" list, then set the $locked variable
    if ( ! in_array($post_type, $exclude_post_types)) {
        $locked_post_status = TRUE;
    }

    // Don't forget to return this so the filtered content still displays!
    return $bulk_messages;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this will only hide the count. The query "SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY post_status" is making my cms slow. 
The main purpose is to make cms load fast. This query is taking more than 15 seconds to execute.

Comment: No, this prevents the counts from being calculated.  I've tested.  If you have different test results, let me know - but in my testing, it completely prevented the counts from being calculated.

Comment: I will confirm this on Monday after trying on my staging server with records more than 5 lakhs. Now I tested on my local development server. It's having only records less than 100.

Comment: I've confirmed via tracing the WP code that this absolutely does prevent the site from loading the counts.

Comment: Is it possible to add some custom links after removing the post status ?
<pre> <code> ( <li class="all"><a class="current" href="edit.php?post_type=post">All</a> |</li>
<li class="all"><a class="all" href="edit.php?post_type=post&post_status=publish">Published</a> |</li> )

Comment: It may be.  However, if this answer solved your stated issue with the long queries being executed, please accept this answer and ask a new question about adding these links.

Comment: Are you certain this function is running? How have you "proven" it?

Comment: I used Query Monitor plugin to track the queries executed in the background.
I got the error. The wp_posts table got corrupted and because of this the index of the table had gone. This had caused the query took long time to execute. I repaired the table and the query is working very fast. Sorry for the trouble.
Thanks every one for your support.

Comment: @modellita - Please upvote this answer, if it helped.  I've invested a lot of time / energy into helping you, and it's the courteous thing to do on SO to upvote / accept answers if they are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this solution.

```
//Disable Article Counter - query runs for about 1-2 seconds
        add_filter('admin_init', function () {
            foreach (get_post_types() as $type) {
                $cache_key = _count_posts_cache_key($type, "readable");
                $counts = array_fill_keys(get_post_stati(), 1);
                wp_cache_set($cache_key, (object)$counts, 'counts');
            }
        }, -1);
        add_action('admin_head', function () {
             $css  = '<style>';
             $css .= '.subsubsub a .count { display: none; }';
             $css .= '</style>';

             echo $css;
        });
```

the post counter uses the wp-cache, the idea behind this approach is, to prefill the cache with the "correct" object containing 1's (0 would skip the status from being clickable) - at the earliest moment.

it results in all stati being displayed - with 1's and the query is not run et-all
in addition it returns a css snippet to hide the `(1)`

[image]