# WordPress/WooCommerce - remove wp_count_posts call in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There's a call to `wp_count_posts()` on every page in wp-admin. I would think it should only happen on the product pages. Is there a way to disable the call on all pages but products? Our site has over 100,000 products, and this call slows down wp-admin pages.

The following is the caller log from Query Monitor

```
wp_count_posts()
wp-includes/post.php:2859
WC_Install::is_new_install()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-install.php:399
WC_Admin_Notices::init()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-notices.php:58
WC_Admin->includes()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin.php:62
do_action('init')
wp-includes/plugin.php:470
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following. Add following function in your theme functions.php . All credits goes to - [wordpress remove post status count from cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517241/wordpress-remove-post-status-count-from-cms)

I have edited $post_type where we want all post types and $exclude_post_types changed to product over page post type.

```
add_filter('bulk_post_updated_messages', 'suppress_counts', 10, 2);

// We need to let the function "pass through" the intended filter content, so accept the variable $bulk_messages
function suppress_counts($bulk_messages) {
    // If the GET "post_type" is not set, then it's the "posts" type
    $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

    // List any post types you would like to KEEP counts for in this array
    $exclude_post_types = array('product');
    // Global in the variable so we can modify it
    global $locked_post_status;

    // If the post type is not in the "Exclude" list, then set the $locked variable
    if ( ! in_array($post_type, $exclude_post_types)) {
        $locked_post_status = TRUE;
    }

    // Don't forget to return this so the filtered content still displays!
    return $bulk_messages;
}
```

Comment: No luck, the wp_count_posts() function still runs, and therefore the SQL.

Comment: One thing I found, in Query Monitor, is that wp_count_posts is being called by WC_Install::is_new_install(). Maybe there's a way I can override this function (it's fairly small).